# Is there a way to access a child object in typescript by chaining variable name

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code I am trying to replace:

```
this.selectedArray1.indexOf(someIndexObject);
```

The code I am trying to replace it by:

```
var someVariable = "selectedArray1"
this[someVariable].indexOf(someIndexObject);
```

When I do the above replacement though it gives me a compile error

```
TS2538: Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type
```

Is doing something like this possible in typescript?

Comment: yes, typescipt is superset of javascript. so anything possible in js is possible in ts.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? TypeScript is a super set of JavaScript that allows type definitions... doesn't change the core usage of the language.

Comment: Yes it works, try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will prevent you from doing this by default, unless it can prove the string is a key of the type or the type has an index signature

With something known to be a key:

```
class Foo {
    selectedArray1 = [];
    method(){
        this['selectedArray1'] //ok the result is of the same type as the field
        const s = 'selectedArray1'; // ok
        this[s] // ok, the result is of the same type as the field
        var someVariable = "selectedArray" + 1 // not provable to be a key
        this[someVariable]  // error
        this[someVariable as keyof this] // but ok with an assertion, but is a union of all field types of this
    }
}
```

Or with an index signature:

```
class Foo {
    [s: string] : any
    selectedArray1 = [];
    method(){
        var someVariable = "selectedArray" + 1 // not provable to be a key
        this[someVariable]  // ok, anything goes is of type any
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great